# Maven build fails during Java 8 to 17 upgrade: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile)

Tags: java, maven, upgrade, checker-framework

I am trying to upgrade a Java project from Java 1.8 to Java 17, it is built with Maven 3.9.3 and has Checker framework as a dependency. When it was used with Java 1.8 on3e of the dependencies included was jdk8, that I removed since currently I am upgrading the project to Java 17:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.checkerframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdk8</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.10</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Read the Checker framework documentation and added the POM settings for versions of Java above 8:

```
<profiles>
 <profile>
      <id>checkerframework-jdk9orlater</id>
      <activation>
        <jdk>[9,)</jdk>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <fork>true</fork>
              <compilerArgs combine.children="append">
                <arg>-J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                <arg>-J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                <arg>-J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                <arg>-J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                <arg>-J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                <arg>-J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                <arg>-J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                <arg>-J--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
              </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <properties>
        <!-- Needed for animal-sniffer-maven-plugin version 1.19 which is broken (version 1.20 is fixed). -->
        <animal.sniffer.skip>true</animal.sniffer.skip>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

Also made all the dependency versions related to this framework to be equal (3.36.0).

My Maven version is:

```
mvn -v

Apache Maven 3.9.3 (21122926829f1ead511c958d89bd2f672198ae9f)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.9.3
Java version: 17.0.8, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 11", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

```
java --version

java 17.0.8 2023-07-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.8+9-LTS-211)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.8+9-LTS-211, mixed mode, sharing)
```

JAVA_HOME:

[image: JAVA_HOME]

If I try to build (mvn clean install) with the previous version of Checker Framework used (1.9.10), the build fails due to:

```
Compilation failure
[ERROR] error: SourceChecker.typeProcessingStart: unexpected Throwable (RuntimeException);
message: Could not determine version from property java.version=17.0.8;
invoke the compiler with -AprintErrorStack to see the stack trace
```

If I change the Checker framework versions everywhere to the latest 3.36.0, I get:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project. Compilation failure

at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:333)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1310)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:198)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
```

It seems to be a Mojo Exception, so something wrong with the maven-compiler-plugin settings:

It used to be with souurce and target java version set to 1.8 but I changed it to 17. Anyway compilation is unsuccessful:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.10.1</version>  
  <configuration>
    <source>17</source>
    <target>17</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I tried to delete .m2 folder and rerun ```mvn clean install``, cleaned IntelliJ cache and it did not help. In IntelliJ's Project Structure the version is set to 17. In my POM it is also 17:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

So, everything seems to be correct. Anyway it does not build successfully. Could you, please, try to help me? I searched a lot in internet but none of the given solutions worked for me.

Comment: The first thing I see is you are using very old version... on central there are versions like 3.36+ I would suggest to check the manual and upgrade... at first...

Comment: Check this: https://checkerframework.org/manual/#maven

Comment: @khmarbaise
I do not know what do you mean, that's what I see on Central: 3.36.0 seems to be the latest one:
Version  Repository Usages Date
3.36.x  3.36.0 Central          0             Jul 04, 2023
3.35.x  3.35.0 Central          0             Jun 01, 2023
3.34.x  3.34.0 Central          0             May 02, 2023

Comment: @khmarbaise Yea=s, I read this page, I made the setting in my POM based on this page, including the settings for the maven-dependency-plugin but I forgot to mention it in the dsescription of the issue.

Comment: But the dependency has a very old dependency... that looks wrong...